# after launching StartUpdatingLocation (), run another method - every time the location is updated

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

after launching StartUpdatingLocation(), run another method - every time the location is updated.

I tried to call the `MethodToRun()` method in `public LocationManager ()`

```
public LocationManager()
        {
           this.locMgr = new CLLocationManager
           {
               PausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
           };
           locMgr.AllowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true;
           locMgr.DesiredAccuracy = 1;
           locMgr.DistanceFilter = 1;
           locMgr.StartUpdatingLocation();

MethodToRun();

}

async public void MethodToRun(){ 
// here I send the data to the server
// code ...
}
```

but the data is sent to the server only once.

```
public LocationManager()
        {
           this.locMgr = new CLLocationManager
           {
               PausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
           };
           locMgr.AllowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true;
           locMgr.DesiredAccuracy = 1;
           locMgr.DistanceFilter = 1;
           locMgr.StartUpdatingLocation();
}

async public void MethodToRun(){ 
// here I send the data to the server
// code ...
}
```

I need the data to be sent every time the location data is updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement and assign a `ICLLocationManagerDelegate` instance to the instance of `CLLocationManager` that you have created.

In `ICLLocationManagerDelegate` is a callback from the location manager called `UpdatedLocation` (ObjC: `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:`).

So add `ICLLocationManagerDelegate` to an existing class or make a new one and implement `UpdatedLocation`:

```
public class ALocationDelegate : NSObject, ICLLocationManagerDelegate
{
    [Export("locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:")]
    public void UpdatedLocation(CLLocationManager manager, CLLocation newLocation, CLLocation oldLocation)
    {
        // do something with the updated location (newLocation)
    }
}
```

Now on your CLLocationManager instance, assign an existing instance (or create a new one) of that delegate:

```
locMgr.Delegate = new ALocationDelegate();
```

re: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanagerdelegate